Is this a "good" PCB layout for the BQ25798 IC?
I want to know if this is a good PCB layout. The ground pours are on the top and bottom layers. This is a two-layer PCB design.
The PCB is based on the BQ25798 IC from TI. The blue traces are all the low-voltage signals.
Are there any glaring mistakes made, that I over looked with respect to the BQ25798 IC routing and placement?




EDIT 1:



What is the max voltage of the solar inputs/outputs?

@VoltageSpike according to the datasheet it is 30V.

There's no ground, and I see a counterfeit aliexpress LM2596 module. Any reason not to use 4 layers?

This layout absolutely needs to be 4 layers, with a solid ground plane.

Add at least 3 fiducial marks, your assembly house will like you.

Problem 1: Counterfeit LM2596 module.
All these should be assumed fake. See these links: 0 1 2 3. It will kinda work, but it will draw high idle current, have high ripple, bad regulation, terrible efficiency, then after a while the high-ESR caps will die.
If you don't feel like designing one, get a DC-DC from a reputable manufacturer, there are plenty from Traco, Recom and others from the usual sources (Farnell, Mouser, Digikey...)
Problem 2: No ground
There is no ground plane. There are bits of copper fill that are connected to net "GND" so the layout software is happy, but that won't work. The reason to use a ground plane is low impedance, especially low inductance, which is extremely important for a DC-DC as any extra inductance results in voltage spikes. \$ e=L \frac{di}{dt} \$ so if it switches 5A in 10ns, with L=10nH, you get a 5V spike or dip. If you get a 5V dip on a 5V supply it drops to zero and the chip will probably reboot, or the spikes will fry the chip, or it won't meet its specs.
If this is a DIY one-off, considering 4 layer prices from shops like JLCPCB, there is no reason not to.
Top layer - components and traces
Layer 2 - Ground plane, no traces, no slots, and no rows of close vias creating cuts or slots
Layer 3 & 4 - everything else
Besides that, some notes:
I see lots of 2 pin 0.1" headers. It is simpler to use a 2xN header with all the pins, especially for the one with "Prog" and "Ilim" configuration resistors. Just put a 12x2 header... and label it so what each position does is readable on the silkscreen. Likewise, for all your headers which I assume are test points, adding a little "+" to the positive side helps.
There are too many ceramic caps. The point of ceramic caps is low inductance because they're small and close to the board which results in small loop area. But if the ground connection is not also low inductance it is pointless. With 4 layers, layer2 is only 0.2mm below, so if you put 2 vias per cap ground pad you get extremely low inductance.
You should follow the datasheet recommended layout, especially for the 2 caps on top of the chip, and the large number of vias on the ground pin. With 4 layers there should also be vias in the top copper PGND pour to connect to the ground plane.

If it's simpler, you can put the inductor on the bottom.
There are no mounting holes. How will you secure the board?


Here's a suggestion with the inductor on the bottom, better placement of boost caps, and input/output decoupling caps. I did not add copper pours but they're needed.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. Locally I can get a 2 layer PCB manufactured. If I go to 4 layer then I have to go to the international vendors like PCBWay. This will cost me 2 times the price. This is personal project, so cost is a big factor. I didn't implement the exact layout as per the datasheet because the local manufacturer minimum via size will not work with the datasheet recommendation under the IC. I did do a copper ground pour top and bottom but hide it, so the PCB layout was more clear (I will add ground stitching vias as well).

I am using sticky rubber pads on the bottom of the PCB, so no mounting holes required, hmmmm but I will put them just in case. Thanks for that, Always an oversight.

JLCPCB does 4 layers for $7 (plus shipping). Even with stitching vias I don't think it will be good, there are too many cuts in the bottom ground and the chip's ground connection which carries the whole switching current has too much inductance. For 2 layers and big vias I think you'd have to get creative with capacitor placement, if you hand solder it's not a problem.

My quote says $60... on JLCPCB. "current has too much inductance" how did you determine or see there is too much inductance?

Just eyeballing it, the trace is too skinny and the via too far... what's the track/space and via size? I'll give it a try

via size I used was 0.3mm/0.6mm and track size is 0.2mm

I have put the inductor on the bottom, which decreased the IC gnd track lenght

I put it in the answer. If you put the inductor on the bottom like you did, you can then move the input/output decoupling caps closer.

The high speed switching occurs on SYS, PMID, SW1, SW2 so the decoupling caps for SYS and PMID (which I called IN and OUT in my pcb) need to be very close. Especially the two small ones on top of the chip. The two BTST caps also need to be close. I put them on top to have less holes in the ground plane on bottom (less cuts) and they're right on top of the inductor pins which is convenient. The other power rails don't have high speed switching, so it's not a problem to use longer traces or put the decoupling caps further away.

If you put the inductor on the bottom, you can put the caps for SYS and PMID where the inductor was on top, which should leave plenty of space to move the VBUS and BAT caps out of the way to give priority to BTST caps. Also look at your STAT and SDRV traces: you can go longer on top layer, to put the via further away from the chip, so the cut in the ground plane due to trace on bottom is also further away.

Firstly thank you for taking the time to answer and also assist in provided a layout!. I do not think the IC will be very happy with the inductor placed directly below it. "Route BATP away from switching nodes such as SW1 and SW2." Pin BATP seems like a sensitive analog signal. Hence the inductor will be placed more upwards on the bottom layer away from the BATP pin.

BATP senses battery voltage so yeah you can move the inductor up a little.

Getting a good performing layout with a converter like this is a challenge with only two layers. A few things jump out at me. It looks like the switching nodes that connect to the inductor have many vias that drill down to the bottom layer and large pours underneath the inductor. Why is this? In the reference layout the vias are to bring these traces back up under the micro on an internal layer, so that smaller value and package capacitors can be placed close the the IC package.
Since you are only using two layers and bringing these traces back on the top layer, there is no need for these vias and bottom layer pours that I can see (they are not connected to anything?), and these will significantly affect EMI and performance. If you do use the bottom layer for these inductor switching nodes, make the pours or traces as short as possible, don't have any excess pour going back under the inductor package. I suggest going back through the layout guidelines in the datasheet (section 12) and working systematically top to bottom. For example, point #1 has not been implemented and is quite critical.

"don't have any excess pour going back under the inductor package" please elaborate on this point, why is this "bad"?
